# How does the optimization option in GCC 7.5.0 change the address order of the global variables?

Tags: c, optimization, linker, memory-address, gcc7

When I was reading the 7th chapter of CSAPP, I came across a problem that I still can't solve till now.

**foo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f(void);

int y = 15212;
int x = 15213;

int main(void)
{
    f();
    printf("x = 0x%x y = 0x%x\n", x, y);
    printf("x address = %p, y address = %p", &x, &y);
    return 0;
}
```

**bar3.c**

```
double x;

void f()
{
    x = -0.0;
}
```

I compiled these two pieces with options shown below. Providing IEEE754 expression and some knowledge about linkers, I can understand why "test2" gets the following results (y = 0x80000000 and x = 0x00000000).

Results:

```
link@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ gcc -Wall -o test2 foo.c bar3.c
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: alignment 4 of symbol `x' in /tmp/ccqoQr0c.o is smaller than 8 in /tmp/ccmrFBLe.o
link@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ gcc -Wall -Og -o test3 foo.c bar3.c
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: alignment 4 of symbol `x' in /tmp/ccu0POss.o is smaller than 8 in /tmp/ccL8gbUH.o
link@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ./test2
x = 0x0 y = 0x3b6c
x address = 0x55616c976014 y address = 0x55616c976010
link@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ./test3
x = 0x0 y = 0x80000000
x address = 0x55d6dd75a010 y address = 0x55d6dd75a014
link@ubuntu:~/Desktop$
```

**But how does the optimization option in GCC 7.5.0 change the address order of the global variable x and y, could you please provide me some infomation concerning this part?**

I've tested -O1,-O2,-O3 etc. The results are the same.

I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: I'm sorry, in fact the exact outputs are shown in the link, it is a photo in fact. Maybe I can copy the results in my main context.

Comment: Right, missed the link. Please copy as plaintext

Comment: Ok, I've added this part of information.

Comment: Different optimisation options result in (often very) different code. So why should the addresses be the same?

Comment: Hey, I just found a question with the exact same code. Is it your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471626/c-ld-link-time-error-with-global-variables

Comment: Those warnings `Warning: alignment 4 of symbol...` are suspicious...

Comment: Ah, its a code from the same book. Isn't it explained in there?

Comment: Disassemble, and look at the map file, that might not explain, why, but how it changed. Optimization does funny things, in general. Why are you surprised?

Comment: It's undefined behavior, so the compiler might generate any random goo as it pleases, optimization or no optimization.

Comment: @DijskstraLink When there is an undefined behavior in the program, the optimization might do very wild things. Reasoning about this can be done only based on the knowledge of this specific compiler/optimizer internal workings.

Comment: @Lundin In this case shouldn't the linker emit a clearer diagnostic message, even an error?

Comment: Especially GCC sorts variables not by name or by appearance, presumably by some kind of hash on their names.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I wish it would :) Got confused myself about what is going on here

Comment: @Jabberwocky You mean like "linker error: 1"? :) On a serious note it might be more interesting to dig into the internal object files here, see if some internal name mangling was used and "which x" that corresponds to the x of the output.

Comment: @thebusybee thanks for your advice, I've just do the same work with clang compiler, and the address didn't change for optimization.. Interesting.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes maybe I should have a deeper look at the the warning.... Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Lundin Seems compiler got his temper..omg..thankyou.

Comment: Try to compile and link also with `-flto`, then the linker will give a warning.

Comment: @ninjalj Thank you, -flto option is very clear.